# Is there a way to pre-compress docker images before pushing?

Tags: docker, compression, docker-registry

I'm in the progress of pushing some docker images through the internet to our host. Seeing as Docker compresses the images on the fly, and the CLI reports total image size before compression, I used `nethogs` to watch the uploading progress - It seemed to be stalling because of compression, as the upload speeds were way below where I expected them to be.

I expect to be uploading this image quite a few times - Is there a way I can cache Docker's compressed image and just push it through later?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? For various crazy reasons I have a 150GiB (!) uncompressed image, that when gzipped is _mere_ 10GiB. However, it seems that `docker push` is redoing all that work again.

Comment: @EngineerBetter Nope, I gave up on it (my case was way less extreme), but I'd really love to know the answer

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation the data is compressed before upload automatically.

> Progress bars are shown during docker push, which show the uncompressed size. The actual amount of data that’s pushed will be compressed before sending, so the uploaded size will not be reflected by the progress bar.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/

Comment: OP was asking how to do this before the push command.